# Writing shp file from url json

Tags: python, json, type-conversion, shapefile

I'm trying to wirte an shp file from https://dnrmaps.gov.nl.ca/arcgis/rest/services/GeoAtlas/Land_Use/MapServer/5.

With this chunk of code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://dnrmaps.gov.nl.ca/arcgis/rest/services/GeoAtlas/Land_Use/MapServer/5'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

I get to write `b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n    <style type="text/css">\n      html, body {\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;\n        font-size: 10pt;\n        background-color: #ffffff;\n      }\n      h1, h2 {\n        height: 82px;\n        text-indent: -999em;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        margin: 0;\n      }\n      div {\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n      }\n      div.header {\n        \n        height: 82px;\n      }\n      div.sidebar {\n        width: 195px;\n        height: 200px;\n        float: left;\n      }\n      div.main {\n        padding: 5px;\n        margin-left: 195px;\n      }\n      \n      h3 {\n        margin: 36px 0;\n        font-size: 16pt;\n      }\n      \n      h2.GNLlogo {\n        background: url(data:image/png;base64,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);\n        width: 128px;\n        height: 64px;\n        margin: 48px auto;\n      }\n      \n    </style>\n    <title>\n      Your request cannot be processed at this time\n    </title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <div class="header">\n    </div>\n    <div class="sidebar">\n      <h2 class="GNLlogo">\n        logo\n      </h2>\n    </div>\n    <div class="main">\n      <h3>\n        Your request cannot be processed at this time\n      </h3>\n      <div class="notice">\n        \n        <p>\n        </p>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </body>\n</html>'` as output but struggle to print this as an shp has been an unstoppable fight against `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Could someone please help to see if it might be the solution I need?

Comment: What you get returned is not JSON but HTML, hence you cannot parse it as JSON. You need to hit [`https://dnrmaps.gov.nl.ca/arcgis/rest/services/GeoAtlas/Land_Use/MapServer/5?f=pjson`](https://dnrmaps.gov.nl.ca/arcgis/rest/services/GeoAtlas/Land_Use/MapServer/5?f=pjson) as this returns JSON that you can then parse using `r.json()` in case of a successful response. I don't know anything about shapefiles but probably there is some library to write to a shapefile from Python. You will at least have the information in your Python program if you follow the steps I've described.

Comment: Changed my input link to that one you shared but it's still giving me 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Comment: Yes that's certainly interesting. I've just tried in in Postman and Node. Works in both. Only  when I use `requests` I seem to get HTTP status code 500. Strange.

Comment: It does also work with Python's URL lib. `import json
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://dnrmaps.gov.nl.ca/arcgis/rest/services/GeoAtlas/Land_Use/MapServer/5?f=pjson") as f:
    result = json.load(f)
    print(result)`. Seems to be an issue with `requests`. Never had that before.

Comment: Ok when you add the user-agent it will also work with requests. `import requests

r = requests.get("https://dnrmaps.gov.nl.ca/arcgis/rest/services/GeoAtlas/Land_Use/MapServer/5?f=pjson", headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"})
print(r.json())`

Comment: Great thank you. now moving on to finding a type conversion tutorial!